# Wrong routing output

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have the follow (and unique) routing rule:

```
Router::connect(
    '/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'dispatch',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

Which send all request to `DispatchController::index()` which is responsive to parse and "re-route" de request, like a dynamic routing. When I access `/sample-page/debug` and do a debug into `$this->request`, the follow is the output I receive:

```
object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'dispatch',
        'action' => 'index',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'sample-page',
            (int) 1 => 'edit'
        )
    )
    [...]
}
```

I want to receive from request the correct values:

```
object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'sample-page',
        'action' => 'edit',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array()
    )
    [...]
}
```

I have tried without success:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:controller/:action/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'dispatch',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current Cake dispatcher and routing?

Comment: @DavidYell I really don't know if it is wrong. I want a output different from Cake's output.